# Which status code to use after deep pagination limit

Tags: pagination, http-status-codes

We have an API and we want to reject requests beyond page 99.

EG:

```
GET example.com/users?page[number]=99 # Allowed, returns 200 OK
GET example.com/users?page[number]=100 # Disallowed, returns ???
```

What is the most appropriate status code to return?

We are considering:

- 400: Too generic
- 403: Most likely
- 410: Gone. Maybe, but the old way was not temporary
- 422: Close, but includes: "the server was unable to process the contained instructions", not quite accurate
- 429: Doesn't honour Retry-After

Answer (score 1):

400-Bad Request: Looks appropriate.
You can include error details in the response body, like a message explaining why it is a bad request (page limit)

403-Forbidden: It does not look to fit well, it is not an access matter.

422-Unprocessable Content: Maybe this one works, once the request syntax is correct.

429-Too Many Requests: It is not the case.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses